# python ex48 hard way No module named ex48

Tags: python

I am a beginner trying to learn Python using Python the Hard Way. I am using Mac OS and am stuck early on ex48.

I am getting:

```
ImportError: No module named ex48
```

when I attempt to run lexicon_tests.py.

There is a similar thread already on stackoverflow, but for Windows, and I've done my best to try to follow the suggestions on it but still getting the error.

The structure of my directories is ~desktop/python/projects/ex48:
Then within that `ex48` I have another directory 'ex48' with `__init__.py` and `lexicon.py`
Also within the first `ex48` I have another directory 'tests' with `__init__.py` and `lexicon_tests.py`.

Perhaps there is a problem in my path? I believe I downloaded the env variable properly, but don't fully understand how that all works...Thanks for the help!

My `setup.py` is:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'ex48',
    'author': 'David Seidenberg',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'davidseidenberg@gmail.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ex48'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'ex48'
}

setup(**config)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well i think you must not run `lexicon_tests.py`
you must run `nosetests` from the root directory of the project.

The thing is that you have a Project:
Project(ex48)
Then the package within ex48:
ex48/ex48

This package contains some modules like `lexicon.py`
[You can add more than that like engine.py , game.py and ... modules in that package.]

in the root directory you must have set a tests directory so your Project structure must be like:

`ex48/
    ex48/
        __init__.py
        lexicon.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        lexicon_tests.py
    setup.py -> in root directory not tests`

so when you run nosetests in root (ex48) you must get the test feedback.

Comment: Thank you. Still having trouble though. In LPTHW, ex48 asks that I construct a working module (lexicon.py) based on a test template (lexicon_tests.py) given to me. I'm stumbling on the first step, which is: "Write the import at the top. Get that to work." As I understand it, that means I should be writing the import in lexicon_tests.py ("from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon") and then making sure it "works". I thought that would mean running lexicon_tests.py in the terminal to make sure there are no errors, but it returns the error I mentioned at the beginning of my question.